# Jquery Ajax - Tumblr API v2

Tags: ajax, jquery, tumblr

I'm trying to delve into the depths of the murky world of Tumblr, and can't understand how to get over the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I believe it may be because I'm getting back json, but trying to use jsonp. Here's what I'm trying to send:

```
$(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url : "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/MyTumblrName.tumblr.com/info",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        api_key : "MyTumblrApi"
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
});
});
```

I get a 200 OK response, and the data but still the above error (which I don't understand and would like to know more about)

Tumblr also kindly points out the following, but I'm unclear on the specifics.

> All requests made with HTTP GET are JSONP-enabled. To use JSONP,
>   append jsonp= and the name of your callback function to the request.
>   JSONP requests will always return an HTTP status code of 200 but will
>   reflect the real status code in the meta field of the JSON response.

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Why do you even care about jsonp? Just use json response...

Comment: If I use JSON I get the following:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/MYTUMBLRNAME.tumblr.com/info?api_key=APIKEY. Origin http://0.0.0.0:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Is that extra, last comma valid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do what Tumblr is telling you to - add a callback function name to the request

```
myJsonpCallback = function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url : "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/MyTumblrName.tumblr.com/info",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        api_key : "MyTumblrApi",
        jsonp : "myJsonpCallback"
    }
});
```

========================================================

EDIT: The console.log thing is a syntax error since I didn't actually test this code.

What happens to success? I don't really know. Try and find out :) It will probably be called but data parameter likely be null or something.
The issue here is that jQuery names it's callback parameter `callback`, where as Tumblr is expecting `jsonp`. Upon 200 response jQuery likely simply `eval()`s the response, which is why  `myJsonpCallback` is actually called.

Comment: That works! One question, how does this work with the 'success' function now?

Comment: I know this is an old reply, but it came up at the top of a search. Wanted to add some info: you still need to specify `dataType: "jsonp"`; however, the Tumblr API is now accepting the "callback" parameter so you no longer need to do it this way. Provide everything required by your API call (in this case, just the `api_key`), and then let the success callback handle the rest. You can still externally define "myJsonpCallback" if you want (it's usually good practice), but invoke it from success.

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't want to use jQuery:

```
var tumblrFeed = document.createElement('script');
tumblrFeed.setAttribute("src", "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{blog.tumblr.com}/posts?api_key={your api key}&jsonp=callback");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tumblrFeed)

function callback(data){
  console.log(data);
}
```

**I've created simple function for this purpose:**

```
function jsonpRequest(opt){
  var params = "";
  var blogName = "{your blog name}";
  var api_key = "{api key}";
  if("selector" in opt){params = "id=" + opt.selector;}
  if(("offset" in opt) && ("limit" in opt)){params = "limit=" + opt.limit + "&offset=" + opt.offset;}
  if("callback" in opt){params += "&jsonp=" + opt.callback;}else{params += "&jsonp=callback";}
  params += "&api_key=" + api_key;      


  var tumblrFeed = document.createElement('script');
  tumblrFeed.setAttribute("src", "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/" + blogName + "/posts?" + params);
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tumblrFeed)
}
```

**How to use it:**
    jsonpRequest({offset: 50, limit: 5});

```
function callback(data){do stuff here ...}
```

**Alternative usage:**
    jsonpRequest({offset: 50, limit: 5, callback: "nameOfMyAmazingCallbackFunction"});

```
function nameOfMyAmazingCallbackFunction(data){do stuff here ...}
```