# aurelia http-fetch-client no access control for tumblr api

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

I'm having a hard time getting a good response from the tumblr api on a GULP localhost.

using postman, I get the proper response from the request URL:

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{any_blog}/posts?limit=5&api_key={key}
```

I can't seem to get the response in my aurelia module though. I keep getting the error

> Fetch API cannot load http://api.tumblr.com/........... 
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
>   Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Code is below:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import 'fetch';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class Users{
  heading = 'Blog Posts';
  posts = [];

  constructor(http){
    http.configure(config => {
      config
        .withBaseUrl('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/')
        .withDefaults({
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
          }
        });
    });

    this.http = http;
  }

  activate(){
    return this.http.fetch('blog/{blog_name}.tumblr.com/posts', { limit: 5, api_key: {api_key} })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(posts => this.posts = posts);
  }
}
```

Comment: To get around the Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue, you need to use [JSONP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about), which [the Tumblr v2 API supports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264446/jquery-ajax-tumblr-api-v2).

Comment: Thanks for the links, that was very insightful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) limitation. You can't make cross-domain requests if your origin is not granted permission. It works for server-side requests of course, that's why you can fetch data without problem in case of nodejs request.

To workaroud the problem you should make use of [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) approach supported by Tumblr. You would also use `HttpClient` for `jsonp` method.

In your case code will be:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class Users{
  heading = 'Blog Posts';
  posts = [];

  constructor(http){
    http.configure(config => {
      config
        .withBaseUrl('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/')
        .withParams({
          limit: 5,
          api_key: '{api_key}'
        });
    });

    this.http = http;
  }

  activate(){
    return this.http.jsonp('blog/{blog_name}.tumblr.com/posts', 'jsonp')
      .then(httpResponse => this.posts = httpResponse.response.response.posts);
  }
}
```

Comment: The only thing I noticed is that you changed this to the http-client that is currently in use. I know this client is intended to be replaced by the http-fetch-client >> https://github.com/aurelia/fetch-client <<

Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Fetch has no jsonp method at the moment. So you should use httpclient for this, at least for now.